# unsigned int array from vector size error

Tags: c++, vector, int, unsigned

I am using C++ Builder and am after some help in setting a const int variable to be the size of a vector.

Here is my code that works, just to show you what does work:

```
vector<appointment> appointmentVector = calCalendar.getAllAppointments();

const int sizeOfArray = 5;
unsigned int arr[sizeOfArray];
```

If I modify the code to be the following:

```
vector<appointment> appointmentVector = calCalendar.getAllAppointments();

const int sizeOfArray = appointmentVector.size();
unsigned int arr[sizeOfArray];
```

I get the following error:

> [BCC32 Error] Assessment2.cpp(357): E2313 Constant expression required

Can I please have some help with this?

**UPDATE**

I am asking this question as I am having problems with the following code:

```
unsigned int arr[2] = {1,8};
unsigned int days;
TMonthCalendar->BoldDays(arr, 1, days);
MonthBoldInfo = days;
```

The BoldDays method requires an unsigned int array, yet I only know of the values at runtime. Can you please advise me on how to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please clarify what is really your question. Is it your first or your updated question?

Comment: array *declarations* in pure-C can have non-const sizing, but not C++. use a std::vector<> instead and it all becomes moot.

Answer (score 0):

Static array requires compile time constants and thus the second code will never compile, because the size of array is not known at compile time. It would be better if you declare arr as a vector or dynamic array.

This is basic C++ question, it is recommended that you go through a beginner C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning a non-constant expression result value (values evaluated at **runtime**) to a const variable whose value needs to be a value generated from a constant expression (values evaluated at **compile-time**) or a literal.

To solve this you should not use `const` in `sizeOfArray`:

```
int sizeOfArray = appointmentVector.size();
```

Also, once you solved the problem above, you should create a **dynamically-allocated array**:

```
unsigned int* arr = new unsigned int[sizeOfArray];
```

Dynamically-allocated arrays allow you to create arrays whose number of elements can be from a runtime value.

Answer (score 0):

A constant expression is one that the compiler can work out the value of. In C++ the size of an array is part of its type and must be given as a constant expression. If the compiler can't determine what value an expression has, you can't use it as the size of an array type.  What you can do is allocate an "array" on the heap and use a pointer to its first element much as you would normally use an array name.